# Time individual linking operation in Ninja

Tags: time, cmake, build, ninja, parallel-builds

Is there a way to time individual ninja building and linking steps ?

Trying to get timings for each ninja operation being performed, but with verbose only the command being executed is shown and the time took is what I am searching for